# How to get the number of form fields in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a django form that I can iterate over, for example, through a for loop:

```
{% for field in form %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Now I'm trying to find out the total number form fields *outside* of the for loop. I have tried the following, but it just returns `0`, even though I have 2 form fields:

```
{{ form|length }}
```

Is there any way to do this?

PS: This is in the context of django-cms 3.1.3, if this helps.

Comment: I have no way to confirm at the moment, but I think `{{ form.fields|length }}` might work.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm thank you. Turn that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly count the fields, rather than just the form itself, such as:

```
{{ form.fields|length }}
```

As seen [in the Django form documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form)

Comment: If you know any relevant pieces of documentation, that would be great as well (I didn't find anything myself, unfortunately, but the documentation is pretty vast).

Comment: @ShangWang do you know any parts of the documentation that mention that you need to refer to `form.fields` instead of `form`?

Comment: Got it added for you, from the forms documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
 {{ form.hidden_fields|length + form.visible_fields|length }}